# Can I stay airside at Stansted after the security gates are closed?

Tags: uk, airport-security, stn

I have an early flight from Stansted. I know that security gates close around midnight and reopen around 2.30am (or similary, I cannot remember exactly).

Right after security there are several comfy chairs one can sleep into which become available after security reopens.

My question: if I manage to pass security before they close the gates will I be able to sleep on the other side or I will be asked to wait outside of the security check.

If the question is too narrow, I welcome considerations on general airport practices on the subject.

Comment: Narrow is good. To broad is bad. :)

Comment: Did you try reading the [Sleeping in Airport page for Stansted](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/europe/londonstansted.htm)?

Comment: I did not know about the page, thanks! Unfortunately, it does not address my question directly and all reviews are very vague on whether people slept airside or not. I hope somebody with a direct experience can write here, then maybe I will give a review myself in december.

Comment: @JoErNanO oh is it? In other community you want broader questions that can help more users, than too narrowly defined ones. Thanks :D

Comment: Standstead claims to be a [24 hour airport](http://www.stanstedairport.com/about-us/london-stansted-airport-and-mag/facts-and-figures/). I can't even find anything saying security closes but it is true there's a gap in flights overnight and if you read between the lines on Sleeping in Airports all the reviews are from people landside ('opposite arrivals').

Comment: It is 24 hour, if you arrive at say 1 am you can enter, but are forced to remain landside until security opens (I know for a fact, cuz I been there). Yeah, sleep in airports review are either unclear or state they were landside. It probably means that you are rejected through security if your flight is too many hours past midnight. I will probably end up giving it a shot anyway and report here.

Answer (score 11):

I work for security at the airport. Your boarding pass to gain access through to security will only be valid if used on the same date as your travelling, so going through the night before is a no no.

Comment: what if one buys a throwaway Ryanair ticket and stays past midnight? would they be asked to leave?

Answer (score 1):

If you want there is also the possibility to find comfortable seats in a room outside the airport that is usually open and free from people. The place is a bar/caffe just outside the airport in front of the bus station.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can stay overnight as long as you pass through security. Be sure to have your ticket present. However, since you have already passed security, you should have no problem. I've done it before.

Here's a link with others who have as well:
http://www.sleepinginairports.net/europe/londonstansted.htm

Comment: Do you know that this is possible at Stansted, or are you just assuming it is because you've done it somewhere else?

Comment: Pretty sure many International airports close some or all of their airsides overnight...

Comment: thanks! I edited my answer and added a link too. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Can you state unambigously in the answer that you went airside and slept there (i.e. passing security gates at some point before midnight)? I will accept your answer then. From sleepinginairports.com people clearly slept landside (or are ambiguos about it).